# Algoritmo que faça a ordenação dos elementos de um conjunto de dados

Tags: c, algoritmo

"Uma equipe precisa escrever um algoritmo que faça a ordenação dos elementos de um conjunto de dados, a partir de um determinado critério definido pela função . Sabendo que o conjunto de dados não possui uma quantidade maior que 100 elementos e que a equipe não tem experiência suficiente para implementar algoritmos muito difíceis. Qual algoritmo você indicaria para a resolução desse problema? Justifique sua resposta."

Pessoal, eu estou quebrando a cabeça com essa questão. É muito importante fazer e compreende-la.
Poderiam me ajudar, por favor? Desde já agradeço!

Comment: Você tem alguma dúvida específica? Não estamos aqui para fazer seus exercícios.

Comment: Concordo plenamente, bigown. Não há uma dúvida específica, é que sou meio iniciante e há dois dias penso e não sai nada. Mas estou de acordo com a política do SO e não voltarei a ser tão geral nas minhas postagens. Obrigado pelo toque!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não vou te dar uma resposta direta pois como comentado pelo Maniero a comunidade do SO desencoraja  fazer a lição de casa alheia. Contudo te dando uma direção caso esteja perdido: o que você precisa é conhecer os [algoritmos de ordenação](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_de_ordena%C3%A7%C3%A3o) clássicos, pesquise sobre [bubble sort](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort), [selection sort](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort), [insertion sort](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort), [merge sort](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) e [quick sort](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) (existem outros mas não vou listar todos). Você precisa entender quais são as vantagens e desvantagens de cada um para poder responder a pergunta com exatidão.

Obs: te deixo uma dica, dependendo do caso não importa qual você use.

Comment: Muito obrigado, Bruno. Estou de acordo com a política da comunidade do SO. Procurarei os caminhos para resolver tomando como base as suas dicas. Valeu!